# Настрока CryptoJS

Tags: javascript

Пытаюсь зашифровать строку qwerty ключем ytrewq при помощи CryptoJS.

```
var ciphertext = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt('qwerty', 'ytrewq');
```

Проблема в том, что при обноввлении страницы, шифрованая строка всегда разная. Как я понимаю, каждый раз генерируется новый вектор что и влияет на исход шифрования. Как можно установить свой вектор, изминить режим шифрования?

Comment: У библиотеки нет явного способа установления своего вектора. Если вам нужно сохранять значение, его можно держать в `localStorage`. Подробнее про алгоритм [тут](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/42642/should-aes-always-give-the-same-output)

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = "qwerty"; 
var Key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("ytrewq"); 
var IV = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("1234567891234567"); 


var encryptedText = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(text, Key, {keySize: 128/8, iv: IV, mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB, padding:  CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7  });  

document.write(encryptedText)
```